# Why did they censor the word spam?

Tags: girls-und-panzer

On OVA episode 2, when all the girls went camping, Yukari showed her collection, rations from different countries, some of Rabbit Team girls started to yell *pam, *pam, *pam, which is I guess come from word spam. But why they censored the word? How could it become something like "eggs, bacon, sausage, and spam"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, it's a parody from a popular Monty Python sketch titled "Spam". It's about two customers who order a breakfast from a menu that includes Spam in almost every dish.

As usual, a lot of other shows also have to censored some brand or replace it with similar names to the real-life brand, so that the producers can avoid copyright issues. Some other show also tend to censored part of the show if it's a parody to other show for same reason.

This is a video from [Girls und Panzer OVA 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlsvLZvAkOg) and [Monty Python - Spam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anwy2MPT5RE)

And this is a picture for comparison in case if the video is removed:

[image: Similarities between the Girls und Panzer parody and the original Monty Python sketch]

Spam is actually used as military food in World War II.

> Spam is a brand of several canned precooked meat products made by the Hormel Foods Corporation. It was first introduced in 1937 and gained popularity worldwide after its use during World War II.<sup>(1)</sup>

[image: A spam can]

Spam was used by U.S. military occupation after World War II into Guam, Hawaii, Okinawa, the Philippine Islands, and other islands in the Pacific as one of their military food.

> The term spam in the context of electronic communications is derived from this sketch.<sup>(2)</sup>

Sources:

- [(1) - Wikipedia: "Spam (food)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(food))
- [(2) - Wikipedia: "Spam (Monty Python)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(Monty_Python))

Comment: The does not address the question why the word **spam** was censored.

Comment: @Paulie_D because it's a parody and a brand, I thought everyone should know that already..

Comment: @Paulie_D I'd imagine it would have something to do with legal issues see Phillip's answer and Oshino's comment above

Answer (score 7):

SPAM® is [a registered trademark by the Hormel Foods Corporation](http://www.hormelfoods.com/Brands/BrandWall/SPAM-Family-of-Products).

As you might have noticed from other productions, Anime usually change or censor any real-world trademarks which appear.

They do this:

1. to avoid legal trouble with trademark owners should they consider their brand misrepresented
2. to not give something away for free [which they might get paid for](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ProductPlacement/AnimeAndManga)